# Disable Chrome Password Manager through Karate framework

Tags: karate

Trying to pick up the right combination of chrome options to disable annoying Password Manager popup after passing login form.

[image]

Here is how I create a driver:

```html
Feature: Driver initialization

 Background:
   * configure retry = { count: 5, interval: 3000 }

  Scenario Outline: using <config>
    * def config = <config>
    * set config.showDriverLog = true
    * configure driver = config
    * driver 'https://google.com'
    * maximize()
    * retry().waitUntil("document.readyState == 'complete'")

    Examples:
      | config |
      | {type: 'chrome', executable: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome', webDriverSession: { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': { credentials_enable_service: false, profile.password_manager_enabled: false }}}} |
```

Also I tried some other combinations with `addOptions: [ ... ]` and so on but nothing helps. Any ideas?

Comment: Hit the "never" button? This should be left up to the user, not the developer.

Comment: We cannot interact with that popup directly from the driver. Also it will be shown on every new run because each new driver is being configured from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard that using incognito mode can solve this.

Comment: Haha, yes, that worked. Not sure if this is correct approach but my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but I found a workaround. Instead of using driver type to be chrome and pointing to the google chrome application installed locally download the chromedriver and use that. I used this on Windows and placed the chromedriver under C:/Windows/ folder. This did not bring up the password manager popup when executing the tests.